# How to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, url, redirect

The problem is I have all determined route but a particular one runs into an infinite loop

```
const rootRoute = {
path: '/',
exact: true,
component: () => <Redirect to="/dashboard" />,
route: PrivateRoute,
```

};

I have a route like this but it keep running into an infinite loop how do I stop the loop only to redirect when not authenticated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply check if authenticated and then use the `Redirect`

```
let isAuthenticated = //check if authenticated here
const rootRoute = {
 path: '/',
 exact: true,
 component: () => isAuthenticated && <Redirect to="/dashboard" />,
 route: PrivateRoute,
};
```